# Is it possible to print the CPU and core using pthreads on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm struggling with getting a multi-threaded app to run on multiple cores. I've looked into affinity, scheduling, etc. Is there a way to find out the CPU Id that any thread is running on? I'm using sched_getaffinity now - but I think that is related to the process id, not the thread within the process. The mulit-threaded app works great on Windows, but seems to be CPU bound (using only one CPU) on linux

**Update**:

If my linux app launches 64 threads - I still only have one pid right? It's still my understanding that each thread launched can run on a different CPU/core on the target hardware, right?

A sample app is here : [How do I make a multi-threaded app use all the cores on Ubuntu under VMWare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488432/how-do-i-make-a-multi-threaded-app-use-all-the-cores-on-ubuntu-under-vmware)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What core is a given thread running on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819655/what-core-is-a-given-thread-running-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your first question

> Is there a way to find out the CPU Id
>   that any thread is running on? I'm
>   using sched_getaffinity now

[`sched_getaffinity`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html) doesn't return the CPU, it returns a mask of eligible CPUs. It says:

> The affinity mask is actually a
>   per-thread attribute that can be
>   adjusted independently for each of the
>   threads in a thread group.

And then

> If you are using the POSIX threads
>   API, then use
>   pthread_setaffinity_np(3) instead of
>   sched_setaffinity().

To simply find out the CPU used, `/proc/[pid]/stat` has a "processor" field:

> `processor` %d (since Linux 2.2.8)
>                             CPU number last executed on.

#### Your second question:

> The mulit-threaded app works great on
>   Windows, but seems to be CPU bound
>   (using only one CPU) on linux

Show the smallest example that exhibits this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I am trying pthread_setaffinity_np now. For an example app see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488432/how-do-i-make-a-multi-threaded-app-use-all-the-cores-on-ubuntu-under-vmware

Comment: The information in `/proc/[pid]/stat` is about the process with the given PID. To get the same statistics about a thread, see `/proc/[pid]/task/[tid]/stat` instead where `[tid]` is the thread ID. The [`proc(5)` man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) documents the fields in these `stat` files.